# How to ensure my LEDs are disabled on startup with sysfs on my SBC

Tags: linux, kernel, gpio, sysfs

On my SBC I have a RGB LED that I can control through `sysfs` and GPIO pins. However, on startup the LED are on until the `/etc/init.d/rcS` is started. Just after that I am able to control the LEDs

How can I ensure that these LEDs/GPIO pins are disabled by default on startup?

| Component | Specification |
| --- | --- |
| SBC | Radxa Zero v1.51, 2GB RAM, 8GB eMMC, 4 Cores |
| SOC | S905Y2 |
| Processor | ARM Cortex-A53 |
| Architecture | ARMv8-A |
| WiFi/BT | [AP6256](http://files.pine64.org/doc/datasheet/PinebookPro/AP6256%20datasheet_V1.7_12282018.pdf), BCM43456/BCM4345C5, b/g/n/a/ac - BT5.0 |
| OS | Buildroot 2022.11, System V |
| Kernel | Latest CIP SLTS version (5.10.145-cip17) |
| Bootloader | Custom [U-Boot 2021.01](https://github.com/radxa/u-boot/tree/radxa-zero-v2021.01) with vendor FIP |
| Pinout | [Link](https://wiki.radxa.com/Zero/hardware/gpio) |
| Quick Reference Manual | [Link](https://dl.radxa.com/zero/docs/hw/S905Y2%20Quick%20Reference%20Manual%20v0.7.pdf) |

Comment: First of all you need to find out what is reset state of your pin. Maybe LED is driven since powering on the SBC. If it's not, you need to check your device tree whether there is gpio node. Check https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/gpio/gpio.txt